# PowerShell - No mapping between account names and security IDs was done error

Tags: powershell

I'm having the following issue when trying to create a share and giving permissions to an ms-DS-Group-Managed-Service-Account:

```
New-SmbShare -Name "Test" -Path "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Other" -FullAccess {Get-ADServiceAccount -Filter 'Name -like "*APP" -or Name -like "*SB"' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name}
```

Apparently the issue I am having is that it cannot retrieve the account information of the service accounts. Can anyone guide me in the right direction please?

Comment: What happens if you manually add a service account name instead of looking it up in AD?  What format are the names returned in by `Get-ADServiceAccount`? Is it a valid one for the `-FullAccess` parameter?

Answer (score 2):

first get the AD group in to a variable
e.g:

```
$adgroup = get-adgroup -identity "xyz group"
```

after getting AD group use its name and it worked for me

e.g:

```
new-smbshare -name "test_share" | grant-smbshareaccess -AccessRight change -account $adgroup.Name
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following method worked instead:

```
$ServiceAccount = Get-ADServiceAccount -Filter 'Name -like "*APP" -or Name -like "*SB"' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

New-SmbShare -Name "Test" -Path "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Other"

#Creating a share
ForEach ($Account in $ServiceAccounts) {
Grant-SmbShareAccess -Name "Test" -AccountName $Account -AccessRight Full -Confirm: $false
```